# Boost using async_write sends strange data

Tags: boost

I'm trying to develop a simple chat program using Boost. I came accross strange situation. I use netcat to listen at specific port while I run the program that's sending a simple text. Connection is established but the text is messed up. Actually instead of whole line I sometimes get one random characters or two. Im putting the code down below:

```
#include "lib/client.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cout << "Wrong use. After specifying executable, add host and port\n";
        return 0;
    }
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    auto endpoint = resolver.resolve({argv[1],argv[2]});
    Client c(io_service, endpoint);
    std::thread t([&io_service](){ io_service.run();});
    std::string text = "Welcome host!";
    c.add_msg_to_deque(text);
    t.join();
    c.close();


    return 0;
}
```

And here are client methods:

```
#include "../lib/client.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Client::connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint){
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket, endpoint,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
          }
        });
}

void Client::close()
{
    ios.post([this]() { socket.close(); });
}

void Client::add_msg_to_deque(const std::string& msg){
    ios.post([this,msg](){
         write_msg_deque.push_back(msg);
         send_msg();
     });
}

void Client::send_msg(){
    boost::array<char,128> buf;
    std::string temp_string = write_msg_deque.front();
    std::copy(temp_string.begin(),temp_string.end(),buf.begin());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf,temp_string.size()),[this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t){
        if(!ec){
            write_msg_deque.pop_front();
            if(!write_msg_deque.empty())
                send_msg();
        }
        else{
            socket.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed the size of array in send_msg() and it worked. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `async_write` with local data it is bad idea. `async_write` returns immediately. After calling `async_write` your method `send_msg` terminates, so local data (`buf` array) is destroyed before your message is sent. You can use a synchronous version of IO functions to send data or keep `buf` as member of your class to provide data exists until data is sent successfully.